# Error of not being able to look at the website I am creating

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

so I am a beginner coder, who is using firebase to create a code that would allow me to send data that is continuously created to a self-created website. So far, I have managed to create a cloud function that allows me to do so. I am now working on the website that would allow me to send the necessary data to that website. When I try to use the command firebase-serve --only "hosting,functions", I would get an error when I click the URL link that says CANNOT GET/. Here is the code that I am working with so far

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');
var hbs = require('handlebars');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = express();

app.engine('hbs',engines.handlebars);

app.set('views', './views');

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

const { service } = require("firebase-functions/v1/analytics");
const { response } = require("express");

var serviceAccount = require("./unabiz-firebase-firebase-adminsdk-ehtzo-0b37e0cf1f.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "firebase-adminsdk-ehtzo@unabiz-firebase.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  });


async function getFirestore() {
    const firestore_con = await admin.firestore();

    const writeResult = firestore_con.collection('device').doc("device").get().then(doc=> 
        {
            if (doc.exists) {return doc.data();}
            else {console.log("No such document!");}})
    .catch(err => {console.log('Error getting document', err);})

}
```

Here is also my code for my index file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <form>
                <label for="dataId" id="dataId">Data ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="dataId" id="">
                <label for="deviceId" id="deviceId">Device ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId">
                <label for="DateTime" id="DateTime">Date & Time</label>
                <input type="datetime-local" name="DateTime" id="DateTime">
                <button id="readBtn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id>Read</button>
            </form>
        </main>

        <script type="module">
            // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
            // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            const firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyDVYsLyFvqo8jYc28QPiD5Os69PxKvnG1g",
                authDomain: "unabiz-firebase.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://unabiz-firebase-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "unabiz-firebase",
                storageBucket: "unabiz-firebase.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "48829412875",
                appId: "1:48829412875:web:6273116637b54d0bc2b90e"
            };

            // Initialize Firebase
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Do note that I have initialize firebase onto the project, and am using firestore, functions and hosting. I am unsure if I have miss out anything but if anyone is able to help me out quickly that would be very nice.

Comment: Hello, you're doing nice. In the client, you're using the version 9 of the firebase sdk. They've a really good documentation on how to import the products your application needs. For example, if you need to use Firebase Functions, you should import that module. If you need to use Auth, you import that module, and so on. Now, you should define what kind of Firebase function would you use: Http or Callable. Figure out what's best for your project.

Comment: Can you please add the exact error message you are getting after running the command `firebase-serve --only "hosting,functions"`?